# Show position on google map/earth, from gps data, using google API

Tags: gps, google, api

For those that have used google's API for mapping (google maps/earth), I would like to know if it is possible to develop an application to receive NMEA data from a gps receiver, extract position, and show online on a map from google map/earth.

Answer (score 2):

Google Earth 5.2 supports GPS NMEA data:

*"Added file import types: NMEA (.log and .nmea), Garmin GDB, Garmin Training Center, and Ozi Explorer files can now all be read. Garmin fitness extensions are now read from GPX. Extended data for Elevation Profile and Track is handled when available"*

http://earth.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40901

http://earth.google.com/intl/en/download-earth.html

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually an answer to the question, since the question isn't clear if he means 'with live update' or not.

Comment: Google Earth Pro for 'Live Data' http://earth.google.com/intl/en/userguide/v5/ug_gps.html#realtime